# How to get line no in cheerios ? is it version specific

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I wanna to get the line number of html tag . While parsing html using cheerios 
I founded that if I use this {withStartIndices : true} then getting the line no but I am using version   "@types/cheerio": "^0.22.17", "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3"

Here is my code::

```
          // const $ = load(htmlPage, { xmlMode: true, withStartIndices : true });    getting error withStartIndices  that not a property
  const $ = load(htmlPage, { xmlMode: true });

 $('b').each((index, el) => {
  const text: string =  $(el).contents().first().text();
  if (text.toLowerCase().includes('data:')) {
  bottomInfo.isExist = true;
  bottomInfo.lineNo = $(el).get(0);
      /* already tried
           bottomInfo.lineNo = $(el).get(0).startIndex;
        bottomInfo.lineNo = $(el).startIndex;
      */
  }
 });
```

How can i got the line no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of hours I just check that withStartIndices : true  not works for typescript "@types/cheerio": "^0.22.17" I directly use "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3" and it works for me fine